# How to resolve "...Error occurred during the execution of xp_cmdshell"?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, xp-cmdshell

The engineers uses this Access based app that takes data from SQL Server 2005.

The users download a file containing details of parts etc make amendments and upload it again. When the file is upload(checked-in) the information such as the modified date, userId etc is stored in SQL Server. When the user tries to check in they face this error:

[image]

The users that are working from home and use remote desktop connection to login into their account are the only one facing this error. The users that are on the office network do not get this error.

I tried making a proxy account and granting access to the user but that doesn't work.

It below query, I get the following errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GRANT'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near 'SIDNEY\UsersWindowsLoginId'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> Incorrect syntax near 'UsersWindowsLoginId'`

Query:

```
CREATE LOGIN UsersWindowsLoginId

GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO 'SIDNEY\UsersWindowsLoginId';

EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'UsersWindowsLoginId'
USE master;
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO 'UsersWindowsLoginId'

GO
```

Also, this seems to be a recent phenomenon as the users have been working from home for a while now.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to use `xp_cmdshell` in the first place? T-SQL is not a generalized scipting language, it should not be used as such. Powershell, cmd and Python are much better placed for whatever it is you are doing

Comment: I am not doing anything. This is an error that an Access application throws. I don't use this application, I am just trying to resolve the error

Comment: When I said "Why are you trying to use `xp_cmdshell`" the *you* referred to the one who wrote the application, which I assumed to be yourself. I doubt Access is running such code by itself, so it must be the code of your application.

Comment: I did not write the code for this application. It was written years ago. I am not going in the backend of the application and change the code. It is way too risky

Comment: `CREATE LOGIN UsersWindowsLoginId` is incorrect syntax, and any case makes no sense in this context, you need to create an actual login *in Windows* using a `net user` or the User Accounts tab in Control Panel. I don't think `GRANT CONTROL SERVER` is necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

First enable advanced option for run xp_cmdshell, for this need to change 1, below query to enable.Try this

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Thanks and Regards
Aravind

Comment: I have done that already, changed options to 1. When I did it displayed "...changed from 1 to 1"